# Android How to refresh items in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, sqlite

```
SQLController dbcon;
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                     boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
TextView text;
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_details, null);
}
text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text.setText(children);
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, children,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

        AlertDialog.Builder Delete=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        Delete.setTitle("Show Linups Or Delete");
        Delete.setMessage("Press Delete For Remove "+children+" or Press Show Lineups to get Lineups.");
        Delete.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dbcon=new SQLController(activity);
                dbcon.open();
                Cursor c=dbcon.returnData();
                if(c.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do{
                        if(children.equals(c.getString(0))){
                            dbcon.deleteData(children);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Toast.makeText(activity,"Successfully Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        }
                    }while(c.moveToNext());
                }
                dbcon.close();
            }
        }).show();
        return false;
    }
});
return convertView;
}
```

This is my Expandable list adapter's getChildView Method, I am using Sqlite database and I store data to database and need to delete some items also so i use onLongClickListener for Deleting items, when I long click on the item I want to delete a popup appears having delete button, when I click on that button the item from database deleted but the item still appears on that activity until I reopen the application, what I want is when I click on delete button it should be disappear from that list also immediately, Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the adapter for the view. Most adapter have the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method, which updates the data set it is displaying

Comment: i call notifyDataSetChanged() underneath dbcon.deleteData(children) method but not working